# List all AWS RDS instances using AWS .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, rds

I'm trying to list all my RDS instances on AWS, using the .NET SDK for AWS.

I was expecting the SDK to offer something similar to the SDK's EC2 describe-instances, and sure enough, that is part of the CLI, but not so straight-forward in the SDK.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

**Solution**

The AWS .NET SDK (v3) contains a similar construct for RDS as for EC2. I missed that somehow. See my answer with source-code below.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that the procedure to get all RDS instances closely mimic the EC2 way of doing it.

You will need to install the AWSSDK.RDS nuget package

In Package Management Console in VS.NET

> ```
>     Install-Package AWSSDK.RDS
> ```

Once you have done that, you will need to add the necessary assemblies:

> ```
>     using Amazon.RDS;
>     using Amazon.RDS.Model;
> ```

And then you can do something like this:

> ```
>     public static void ListAllRDSInstances(RegionEndpoint region)
>     {
>         var c = new AmazonRDSClient(region);
>         var request = new DescribeDBInstancesRequest();
>         var response = c.DescribeDBInstances(request);
>
>         response.DBInstances
>             .ForEach(instance => {
>               //do stuff for each instance in region
>             });
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [DescribeDBInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_RDS_AmazonRDSClient_DescribeDBInstances.htm). The [DescribeDBInstancesResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_RDS_Model_DescribeDBInstancesResult.htm) has a list of [DBInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_RDS_Model_DescribeDBInstancesResult_DBInstances.htm). That's where you'll find the information on each RDS instance.

Edit: The function and object names are the same but here's the [link for V3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/MRDSRDSDescribeDBInstances.html).

Comment: This is for version 1 of the SDK. We are currently at version 3

Comment: I've found the same feature in v3 now. I missed that somehow